# LiFePo4 Battery Cells, minimum and maximum charge?

Tags: batteries

What are the minimum and maximum voltage levels typically considered for LiFePo4 cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_iron_phosphate_battery#Specifications) states that the minimum discharge voltage is 2.8 and the maximum charge voltage is 3.6. The working voltage is 3.0-3.3.

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but Wikipedia now states the minimum as 2.5 and max as 3.65, but this varies slightly with each manufacturer. One vendor claims internal OV circuitry at 3.95, cut-off at 2.0, and UV at 1.8v.